Is it possible to have this overlap between Goldbach and the twin prime conjectures?
This question is related to this. But, here it is related Goldbach's conjecture.
Any even number greater than $4$ is the result of addition of two prime numbers one of which is the lower of a twin prime or $1$.
Is there a clear counter-example?
Note: number $1$ has been added because as shown in comments number $38$ would be a counter-example.

I can't understand your conjecture statement.  These type of conjectures are possible to be written for the layman.  So if I can't get it 3 reads through, then you have to update your post.

Yes, there is similarity between the two conjectures, and I don't know where now, but I've seen analytical formulas that relate Twins, Goldbach, and probably whether $x^2 +1$ is prime i.o.    Perhaps you can't prove one without automatically proving the other.   So when someone comes out with a paper claiming to have solved several NT conjectures, we shouldn't automatically assume crackpottery.   But we should be aware that these conjectures if one of them falls, a bunch of them will.

The usual first step here would be to do a deep search...how far have you checked?

@SassatelliGiulio, correct. I need to put $1$ to the game. Thanks.

The conjecture probably holds for all $n\not\equiv 2\bmod 3$. There are no modular problems, no counterexamples $<10^6$, and for large $n$ we expect the number of ways to write $n$ as the sum of two primes to grow, so the probability that at least one of them contains a lower twin prime increases.

$188$ is a counterexample: $188-1=11\times 17$, $188-3=5\times 37$ and the lowest in a pair of twin primes, other than $3$ itself, is $\equiv -1\pmod 3$, just like $188$ is.
As a matter of fact, an infinite class of counterexamples is given by the integers which are $\equiv 2\pmod 6$ and $\equiv 3\pmod{\text{composite number coprime with }6}$, and which aren't $1+\text{prime}$.

just wanted to mention that if we extend the primes to the integers, and consider $1,-1$ to be primes, then $(-3,191)$ would qualify.

@Zuhair I'm not here to tweak conjectures. Not my job.

I know! It is just an observation that I found in some sense relevant to this general tweaking line! Also $(-3,41)$ would qualify for the case of $38$, but it looks as if this can break also?!
